# Is “Thoughts on a Clock” a real poem?

Tags: doctor-who, poetry

The poem *Thoughts on a Clock*, by Eric Ritchie Jr., is mentioned in the episode *Time of the Doctor*. Does anybody have a link to the entire poem? Was it written especially for the show, or modified to fit the episode?

The only extract I can find (from the episode) is:

> And now it's time for one last bow
>   Like all your other selves
>   Eleven's hour is over now
>   The clock is striking twelve's."

Answer (score 29):

**I think it was written specifically for the episode.**

Every mention of it that I can find online only refers to it as an “extract” and almost always includes a mention of Doctor Who. I’m also unable to find any mention of Eric Ritchie, poet or otherwise, that doesn’t include a mention of this poem.

As further evidence that this was probably a made-up poem, the [Google Trends for “Thoughts on a Clock” and “Eric Ritchie”](https://www.google.co.uk/trends/explore#q=%22thoughts%20on%20a%20clock%22%2C%20%22eric%20ritchie%22&cmpt=q) are zero until December 2013, when the two phrases suddenly spiked in popularity. If it was a real poem, I’d expect it to show up *somewhere* before it was mentioned in a Doctor Who episode.

(If nothing else, the Doctor Who writers would have Googled it, right? I mean, I know this is a universe with disappearing blue boxes and immortal aliens, but the idea that they use Bing really stretches plausibility.)

[image]

Comment: Also, there's only one person with that name in the US or UK and they weren't a poet; http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Eric_Ritchie_Junior